# write to file from stack

Tags: java, file, stack, filewriter

folks. I'm trying to write to a file from a stack. The stack was created by reading from another file. I'm using the stack so that I can reverse the file I read in. The file names to read and write to are from the command line.
This is how I have my stack implemented:

```
while(read.hasNext()) {
stack.push(read.next());}
```

The code for my other file that the stack is supposed to write to:

```
FileWriter w = null;
        try {
            w = new FileWriter(new File(args[1]));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!stack.isEmpty()) { //this was a while statement
            try {
                w.write(stack.pop());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Didn't make it.");
        }
```

The problem that I'm having is when I run my program, the file I want to write to is created, but nothing gets written to the file. I originally thought that my stack didn't have anything in it (that's why I changed my while statement to an if; it's temporary). The "Didn't make it." didn't print so I now know it's not that. What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you ever close your `FileWriter`? The output may be buffered and never actually transferred to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After **w.write(stack.pop());** call the fush() method:

```
w.write(stack.pop());
w.flush();
```

and you can return the **while** statement. At the end call *w.close();*

Answer (score 1):

the method stack.pop returns an Object if you do not specify at the time of declaration like this 
`Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();`

and after writing you should use `w.flush()` and also you should use the `w.close`.

you should nest the while statement itself into the try block
for instance

```
try {
  while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
    w.write(stack.pop()); // assuming you have declared it as Stack<E>
  }
  w.flush();
  w.close();
 } catch(IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

**EDIT:**

after you are done with `FileWriter` when you close it, that has to nested inside a try catch block to catch any `IOException` if thrown. if you use the `w.write()` method inside the try catch block that is within the while loop then after the `while` loop iteration is over you have to build another try catch to place `w.close()`

Comment: I did specify the stack as a String. It's just much earlier in my code. I'll play around with the try block, but can you tell me what that will change?

Comment: after you are done with FileWriter when you close it, that has to nested inside a try catch block to catch any IOException if thrown.

if you use the `w.write()` method inside the try catch block that is within the while loop then after the `while` loop iteration is over you have to build another try catch to place `w.close()`